# Angular 6, fire an event on the component that is not current route

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular 6 SPA-based application, considering there are two routes A & B, in route B which uses component B, there is a button to open the modal window. now on route A which uses component A, I would like to open the same modal window? first, would that be possible?

I have created a common component communication service as below and injected it into component B, but apparently, that is not working.

```
export class ComponentCommunicationService {
        private open= new Subject();
        public openModal$ = this.open.asObservable();
        open() {
            this.open.next(true);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this for common modals (input modal/confirmation modal) using a `PresentationService`. So anyone in the app that wants to show a confirmation dialog, just imports the service and calls `service.confirm()` and gets back an Observable that completes with the result.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/andreit-note-taker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fpresentation.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable, ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injector } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { first, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from '../components/confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.component';

@Injectable()
export class PresentationService {
  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
  ) {
  }

  show<T>(component: Type<T>, options) {
    return new Observable<T>((observer) => {
      const injector = Injector.create(
        Object.keys(options).map(key => ({
          provide: key,
          useValue: options[key],
        })), this.injector
      );

      const componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
        .resolveComponentFactory(component)
        .create(injector);

      this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
      document.body.appendChild(componentRef.location.nativeElement);
      observer.next(componentRef.instance);

      return () => {
        this.appRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
        componentRef.destroy();
      };
    });
  }

  confirm({ title, message }) {
    return this.show(ConfirmationDialogComponent, { title, message })
      .pipe(
        switchMap(v => v.confirm$),
        first(),
      );
  }
}

interface Type<T> extends Function {
  new(...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Comment: will this be helpful in terms of editing with the same dialog ?, in my case I will be editing some record as well.